# Generating a sequence using kafka and s3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, total-ordering

I need build a global concurrency safe numeric sequence . I have only s3 and kafka at my disposal . The hard requirement here is that there are no collisions of the generated Id. The approach I have in mind is :-

- There will be a kafka topic with single partition called "get-sequence-req" with event schema {"reqId":<string client key>} .
- The response is obtained at "get-sequence-resp" with event schema {"reqId":<string client key>, "seqVal":<integer sequence val> } . Multiple partitions, partitionKey is reqId
- There is a single consumer group with a listener process that maintains a sequence count in a s3 bucket. Its order of processing are -
   1.  receive msg 
  2. read bucket content 
  3. increment and write back ( update the count ) bucket 
  4. publish the sequence response with updated count and reqId 
  5. ack 
  There can be duplicate responses and holes in the observed sequence values, but there will not be a case where same sequence values are reported back. Basically the single partition of request topic ensures that. 
  Is there an issue with this solution?

Comment: Sounds like you have an AWS account not just S3. I'd recommend dynamo for a simple counter, not s3

Comment: I do not want to pay for an additional component over what I am using in that environment .  So exploring if this contraption could work ? or atleast understand why this will not ?

Comment: It'll work fine. It's just not a traditional use case for S3. Kafka can maintain its own global count in Zookeeper or RocksDB KTable